# How do I make data from a fetch display properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, api, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from three different endpoints which works, but when getting the name of the episode "undefined" is returned instead. I'm using the Rick and Morty API for this website. The link to the episodes endpoint https://rickandmortyapi.com/documentation/#episode-schema . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function getCharacters(done) {
    fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            done(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching characters:", error);
        });
}

function getLastKnowLocation(done) {
    fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            done(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching last known locations:", error);
        });
}

function getEpisode(done) {
    fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            done(data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error("Error fetching episodes:", error);
        });
}


getCharacters(data => {
    data.results.forEach(item => {
        const article = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(/*html*/`
        <article class="character-card">
            <div class="image-container">
                <img src="${item.image}" alt="Character">
            </div>
            <div class="character-info">
                <div class="section">
                    <h2>${item.name}</h2>
                    <span class="status">${item.status} - ${item.species}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <span class="greytext">Last known location:</span>
                    <span>${item.location.name}</span>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <span class="greytext">First seen in:</span>
                    <span>${item.episode.name}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </article>
        `);

        const main = document.querySelector("main");
        main.append(article);
    });
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

main {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    gap: 18px;
}

.image-container{
    display: flex;
}

.image-container img{
    width: 229.2px;
    height: 220px;
}

article{
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px #000;
}

.character-card{
    display: flex;
    margin: 13.5px;
}

.character-info{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 13.5px;
    position: relative;
}

.section{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 343.8px;
    height: 64.33px;
}

.greytext{
    color: rgb(158,158,158);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Rick and Morty API</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Rick and Morty API</h1>
    <main></main>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For a character `item.episode` is an array. So, you need to first sort the array based on `air_date` and then get the first item to fetch the `name`.

Comment: You should also get in the habit of using `console.log()` to check what data is in your variables, to debug your own code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each character has an array of episode URL strings. You can grab the first one and fetch the info for that episode in a nested callback.

```js
function getCharacters(done) {
  fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      done(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching characters:", error);
    });
}

function getLastKnowLocation(done) {
  fetch("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/location")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      done(data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error fetching last known locations:", error);
    });
}

const main = document.querySelector("main");

getCharacters(data => {
  data.results.forEach(character => {
    fetch(character.episode[0])
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(episode => {
        main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
          <article class="character-card">
            <div class="image-container">
              <img src="${character.image}" alt="Character">
            </div>
            <div class="character-info">
              <div class="section">
                <h2>${character.name}</h2>
                <span class="status">${character.status} - ${character.species}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="section">
                <span class="greytext">Last known location:</span>
                <span>${character.location.name}</span>
              </div>
              <div class="section">
                <span class="greytext">First seen in:</span>
                <span>${episode.name}</span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        `);
      })
  });
});
```

```css
*,h1{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI',Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif}.character-info,.image-container,.section{display:flex}*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}h1{text-align:center}main{display:grid;grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;gap:18px}.image-container img{width:229.2px;height:220px}article{padding:10px;box-shadow:0 0 1px #000}.character-card{display:flex;margin:13.5px}.character-info{flex-direction:column;padding:13.5px;position:relative}.section{flex-direction:column;width:343.8px;height:64.33px}.greytext{color:#9e9e9e}
```

```html
<title>Rick and Morty API</title>
<h1>Rick and Morty API</h1>
<main></main>
```

### Async version

Here is an `async`/`await` version that is easier to read:

```js
const mainEl = document.querySelector("main");

const main = async () => {
  const characters = await fetchAllCharacters();
  for (let character of characters) {
    const episode = await fetchJsonAsync(character.episode[0]);
    mainEl.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', renderCharacterHTML(character, episode));
  }
};

const renderCharacterHTML = (character, episode) => `
  <article class="character-card">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="${character.image}" alt="Character">
    </div>
    <div class="character-info">
      <div class="section">
        <h2>${character.name}</h2>
        <span class="status">${character.status} - ${character.species}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <span class="greytext">Last known location:</span>
        <span>${character.location.name}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="section">
        <span class="greytext">First seen in:</span>
        <span>${episode.name}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
`;

const fetchAllCharacters = async () => {
  const response = await fetchJsonAsync('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character');
  return response.results;
};

const fetchJsonAsync = async (url) => {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(url);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.statusText);
    return response.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error fetching JSON:', err);
  }
};

main(); // Call main function
```

```css
*,h1{font-family:system-ui,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,'Segoe UI',Roboto,Oxygen,Ubuntu,Cantarell,'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',sans-serif}.character-info,.image-container,.section{display:flex}*{margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box}h1{text-align:center}main{display:grid;grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;gap:18px}.image-container img{width:229.2px;height:220px}article{padding:10px;box-shadow:0 0 1px #000}.character-card{display:flex;margin:13.5px}.character-info{flex-direction:column;padding:13.5px;position:relative}.section{flex-direction:column;width:343.8px;height:64.33px}.greytext{color:#9e9e9e}
```

```html
<title>Rick and Morty API</title>
<h1>Rick and Morty API</h1>
<main></main>
```

Comment: thank you sm. do you mind explaining why you did const mainEL at the beginning? i don't understand the mainEl

Comment: @alessi.gg I renamed your `main` variable to `mainEl` (aka "main element"). To distinguish it from the function declared as `const main` that I added. The `main` function is just a convention used in C and other programming language as the entry-point into the code. I call that function at the very end. That way I can shuffle around the code to flow in a more readable manner. This is due to the fact that JavaScript is a scripting language that is executed top-to-bottom.

Comment: oh ok thak you that makes sense now.